# SharePoint Calculated Column - Showing text value based on date range

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am working on a holiday booking form, the list has three main columns:

"Start Date","End Date" and "Year"

The purpose of the **Year** column is to show what holiday year the holiday has been booked in i.e. 2020/21, 2021/22 etc.  The issue is that the holiday year runs from April to March so simply taking the year value from the Start or End Date columns doesn't work.

**Example**

User books 20th December 2019 to 10th January 2020, this would be a booking in the 2019/20 holiday year.

**Desired Result**

I'd like a calculated column to be able to compare the dates in "Start Date" and "End Date" then output the holiday year i.e. 2020/21.  The tricky bit, and where I am getting really stuck is that this calculation needs to work for future holiday years.

Any thoughts or pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula in the Calculated Column.

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR([start date]))&"/"&CONCATENATE(YEAR([end date]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Emily, in the end I used PowerApps to do the heavy lifting and that seems to be working well.

Comment: Congratulations on solving this issue.